# page cuts off when multiple checkboxes are selected

Tags: php, checkbox

I have a page with some checkboxes on and which works fine if just one checkbox is selected, however if I select 2 or more checkboxes the results show fine but the rest of the page after the script cuts off. any ideas what would cause this to happen.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['criteria']) && !empty($_POST['criteria'])) {
    foreach($_POST['criteria'] as $key => $value) {

        // get the function

        include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/scripts/pagination-functions.php');

        $page = (int)(!isset($_GET["page"]) ? 1 : $_GET["page"]);
        $limit = 14;
        $startpoint = ($page * $limit) - $limit;

        // Runs mysql_real_escape_string() on every value encountered.

        $clean_criteria = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_REQUEST['criteria']);

        // Convert the array into a string.

        $criteria = implode("','", $clean_criteria);

        // to make pagination

        $statement = "table WHERE page IN ('$criteria') ORDER BY long_title ASC";
        if (!$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$statement} LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$limit}")) {
            echo "Cannot parse query";
        }
        elseif (mysql_num_rows($query) == 0) {
            echo "No records found";
        }
        else {
            echo "";
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                echo "" . $row['name'] . "<br />
             " . $row['description'] . "";
            }
        }

        echo "<div class=\"pagination\">";
        echo pagination($statement, $limit, $page);
        echo "</div>";
    }
}

?>
```

If anyone can help or point in the right direction I would be very greatful

Comment: View the page source and check for any PHP errors that are hiding in the HTML source (that cannot be seen in the rendered page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you want to have everything sitting inside that `foreach` loop? It looks like you don't need to have that `foreach` loop in there at all because you're using the criteria items as a group, not individually:

```
$clean_criteria = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_REQUEST['criteria']);
$criteria = implode("','", $clean_criteria);
```

This means that your query will be executed once for every single criteria specified, but every query already looks at all the criteria. You never reference either `$key` or `$value`, so I don't think the loop is useful.

### Reworked code example

```
<?php

if (!empty($_POST['criteria'])) {

    // get the function

    include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/scripts/pagination-functions.php');

    $page = (int)(!isset($_GET["page"]) ? 1 : $_GET["page"]);
    $limit = 14;
    $startpoint = ($page * $limit) - $limit;

    // Runs mysql_real_escape_string() on every value encountered.

    $clean_criteria = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST['criteria']);

    // Convert the array into a string.

    $criteria = implode("','", $clean_criteria);

    // to make pagination

    $statement = "table WHERE page IN ('$criteria') ORDER BY long_title ASC";
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$statement} LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$limit}");
    if (!$query) {
        echo "Cannot parse query";
    } elseif (mysql_num_rows($query) == 0) {
        echo "No records found";
    } else {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            echo $row['name'] . "<br />" . $row['description'] . "<br /><br />";
        }
    }

    echo "<div class=\"pagination\">";
    echo pagination($statement, $limit, $page);
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Nerdwood, however when i remove the loop I get and error on 2 lines of code that mentioned above. also the page source just ends there are no hidden PHP errors

Comment: I get array_map() [function.array-map]: Argument #2 should be an array

Comment: and also implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed

Comment: Sounds like `criteria` isn't being passed through to the script properly then, because the foreach loop wouldn't change that. I'll post a new answer with a code suggestion.

Comment: sorry that was my error have removed the loop and it has fixed the error thanks Nerdwood, musch appreciated. Also just one thing if anyone can help. How can I get the the boxes checked to pass to the next page in the pagination

Comment: Passing the criteria through to the next page will be tricky unless you are getting the user to resubmit a form with the checkboxes in it. It would probably be easiest to use a session to store their criteria preferences.

Comment: No problem. May as well mark it as an accepted answer for those that come looking for a solution!  :)